# My code is running fine, however it won't show the designated files being opened

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
def extraDataRecord(inFile):
    line = inFile.readline()
    if line == "":
        return[]
else:
    parts = line.rsplit("",1)
    parts[1] = int(parts[1])
    return parts

popFile = "GhostTownPop.txt"
areaFile = "GhostTownArea.txt"
denFile = "GhostTownPopDensity.txt"

def main():
    open(popFile, "r")
    open(areaFile, "r")
    open(denFile, "w")
popData = 'extractDataRecord',(popFile)

while len(popData) == 2:
    areaData = 'extractDataRecord',(areaFile)
    Town = popData[0]
    Population = popData[1]
    Area = areaData[1]
    Density = 0.0

if Area > 0:
    Density = Population/Area
denFile.write("%-25s%10.2f\n" % (Town, Density))

popFile.close()
areaFile.close()
denFile.close()

main()
```

When I run the code, nothin shows up, but when I try to cancel it, it says it's running fine.

What should happen is that the data files of Ghost Town populations and areas and writes out to the Ghost Town population density file for each town to a file named “GhostTownPopDensity.txt”.

Comment: Your code has a number of serious problems.  I'm trying to rewrite it for you, but are those all supposed to be CSV files?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I can't understand the description of the problem. What do you think should "show up", where and why? What does "show the designated files being opened" - why should anything appear on the screen just because a file was opened? What do you mean by "cancel it"? What does "it says it's running fine" mean - what is the "it" saying that, and exactly what does "it" "say", and how? "and writes out... file named “GhostTownPopDensity.txt”." Okay, so after you run the program, did you look for the file? Is it there? Does it contain what you expect?

Comment: Also, please check the indentation of your code. If it really appears like that, then there are numerous syntax and logical errors. Otherwise, please read that [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) and make sure you show us the code exactly as you actually have it, since indentation is crucial in Python. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

OK, let me see if I can point out what you did here.

Your code was not "running fine" in any way. You were in an infinite loop doing nothing.  Because of the problems pointed out below, `popData` contains a tuple with 2 strings, thus `len(popData)` was always equal to 2.  You were thus executing the 5 lines in that loop, over and over and over, doing nothing at all.

First, you have an indentation problem.  As written, those three "open" statements were the only thing in `main`, and they would not have executed until all the other code was finished.  Everything down to the `denFile.close()` should have been indented, to be part of the `main` function.  You had the same problem in `extraDataRecord`; the whole `else` clause needs to be indented to be part of the function.

Second, saying `open(popFile,"r")` does nothing.  The `open` function returns a file object.  That's what you need to use in I/O statements.  As it is, you're trying to use the file NAME as an I/O object.

Third, saying `areaData = 'extractDataRecord',(areaFile)` does not call a function.  All that does is create a tuple of two strings,  To call a function, you have to do `extractDataRecord(areaFile)`, with no quotes.

Finally, you called the function `extraDataRecord`, but I'm pretty sure you meant `extractDataRecord`.  I left that alone.

```
def extraDataRecord(line):
     parts = line.rstrip().rsplit(None,1)
     parts[1] = int(parts[1])
     return parts

popFileName = "GhostTownPop.txt"
areaFileName = "GhostTownArea.txt"
denFileName = "GhostTownPopDensity.txt"

def main():
    popFile = open(popFileName, "r")
    areaFile = open(areaFileName, "r")
    denFile = open(denFileName, "w")

    for line in popFile:
        popData = extraDataRecord(line)
        areaData = extraDataRecord(areaFile.readline())

        Town = popData[0]
        Population = popData[1]
        Area = areaData[1]
        Density = 0.0
        if Area > 0:
            Density = Population/Area
        denFile.write("%-25s%10.2f\n" % (Town, Density))

    popFile.close()
    areaFile.close()
    denFile.close()

main()
```

It looks like the two input files must have the same lines in the same order, so you could simplify this somewhat by doing:

```
    for line1,line2 in zip(popFile,areaFile):
        popData = extraDataRecord(line1)
        areaData = extraDataRecord(line2)
```

but that's a micro-optimization.  If they aren't in the same order, then your code won't work.  Let us know.

Comment: When I run the code, an error appears for multiple lines. Line 25 - `main()`, line 13 - `popData = extractDataRecord` and line 2 `parts = line.rstrip().rsplit("",1)` ending with a ValueError: empty separator @TimRoberts

Comment: If you want `rsplit` to split on white space, you'll need to write `rsplit(None, 1)`.  And that's not an error on multiple lines.  It's one error, and the traceback shows you how you got there.

Comment: okay now when I run the code, nothing shows up.

Comment: Nothing shows up where?  You're not printing anything.  You're creating a file called "GhostTownPopDensity.txt".  Does that file get created?  Everything works correctly here.

Comment: It took a minute to fine the file, Thanks A Bunch @TimRoberts !